update/reload/refresh site if new version of one was deployed cloudfront cloudflare react app
Hello I have a problem that our site fails sometimes if there was deployed a new version and user doesn't know about deploy(he doesn't refresh page) and clicks somewhere does something and these actions make requests for files like js chunks, other files, that have been changed, e.g. it was chunk.hash1.js and became chunk.hash2.js and that causes 404 not found and app crash. Any solutions for this issue?
I tried to come up with  something but I haven't done this kind of things before.
Idea 1: to store some cookie of build integrity and then if cookie in a new requests doesn't match previous one then we need to refresh the page to request fresh deployed changes
Idea 2: to have something like websocket on frontend that will get a signal to refresh the page if something changed on backend
I'm not very good at aws, but looks like I'm missing something simpler
